# how to get values from json with unknown ammount of given elements

Tags: javascript, json

Given this json as example:

```
[
   {"offspring0":"John"},
   {"offspring1":"Anna"},
   {"offspring2":"Peter"}
]
```

I can know how many `offspring` are there with:

```
offspringCount = (jsonString.match(/offspring/g) || []).length; //jsonString is the json above
```

This would return 3. **Now, how can i get the value of all those offsprings?** I have tried:

```
json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert(json[0].offspring[0]);
```

But this throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` because `offspring` is not an array.

I also tried:

```
alert(json[0]."offspring0");
```

But getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

My intention is to loop through all the `offspring[number]` and get the values, was expecting something like this:

```
for(x=0; x<offspringCount; x++){
    alert(json[0].offspring[x]);
}
```

**Note** i do not handle the making of the JSON, i only request it to a server.

Comment: Do you have single object with `offspring` properties or array with objects?

Comment: You're making a mistake when creating the array of objects, they should all have **the same key**, not incrementing keys, that way this would be trivial.

Comment: For example `{offspring: "John"}` or, if the offspring-number is important, add that as a second key: `{offspring: "John", offspringNumber: 0}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing this code may help you

```
json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert(json[0]['offspring0']);
```

this means, when you need to loop around your array , you need to do something like this:

```
for(var index = 0; index < json.length; index++) {
    alert(json[index]['offspring' + index]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
var jsonString = '[{"offspring0":"John"},{"offspring1":"Anna"},{"offspring2":"Peter"}]';

var array = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var offsprings = [];
for (var i=0; i<array.length; ++i) {
  for (var key in array[i]) {
    if (key.match(/^offspring[0-9]+$/)) {
      offsprings.push(array[i][key]);
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(offsprings);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```